# IIS 7 redirect to url with specific port number

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I want to configure my website to redirect to a specific URL with a specific port.

For example, `http://www.example.com` should redirect to `http://www.example.net:9090`.

I configured the http redirect module in IIS 7 manager, but it always redirects to `www.example.net` without any specific port. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you write “http://www.example.com” in a browser address bar, the default port used will always be 80.

For this question, I suggest you add a new website for this host on port 80 where you add a redirect in a page to the final page (the other port).

Try using a meta refresh tag in a html page to redirect to an address: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=example.net:9090" />`.

Comment: My problem is now when i get in to www.xxx.com, it only redirect me to www.yyy.com. What I expected is redirect to www.yyy.com:9090.

Comment: please use meta refresh tag in a htm page to redirect to a address: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.yyy.com:2222" />